# Medium-Old YA Sci-Fi TV Series

Tags: story-identification

Having been thinking about some of my favorite Sci-Fi shows from long ago I managed to jog my memory about one I just barely remember.  Hopefully, with the bit of detail I do remember someone might be able to recognize it.  First, the production details:

- It would have been aired ~15-20 years ago in Canada (likely on the then equivalent of the Space Channel, but I don't guarantee that)
- It was in English
- It was definitely not animated, no puppet people either
- It was definitely a series, but I cannot remember the number of seasons it might have run for
- It could have been a rebroadcast of a show earlier, but it was definitely new to myself and the station at the time.
- It was definitely aimed towards a younger audience (Young me at the time would not have been watching an adult TV series)

Now, for what I do remember.  Take everything with a grain of salt, as particulars might also be mixed up with other shows (I'll make note of parts I'm not sure of:

- There were likely three main characters (Could have been more, but three is a definite minimum)
- Each character had a personal fighter/ship, colour coded to their uniform colours (I don't think they were designed as pure fighters, but they definitely had some kind of weapons).
- The show took place in deep space and I don't specifically remember any kind of references to Earth.
- There were definitely FTL jumps, but the terminology used for the technology escapes me.
- There was a large ship capable of devouring asteroids/planets for some reason, likely controlled by whatever passed for the bad guys. (Young me was likely quite impressed by it)
- One particular scene that I have quite vividly (probably from the series premier) had them exploring an abandoned wrecked ship, exterior lights flickering over the ships name (This ship was probably very important and likely became their home base, but I don't guarantee that).

And, sadly, I think that's about all I can confidently remember.  I thank you for indulging me in my little bit of nostalgia with my childhood.

Comment: Good, detailed description! I'm sure someone will be able to find it from this.

Comment: Cartoon or live-action?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'll edit that into the question now, but it was definitely live-action.

Comment: I know it's not a child's series, but have you looked at *Space: Above and Beyond*?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Interesting looking show, but that's definitely not it.  I don't even remember a reference to Earth, let alone a full Earth war.

Comment: Not putting it as an answers because my confidence is low, but could it have been Deepwater Black (released in the US under the name Mission Genesis)?  Was YTV, not Space, but the timeframe's roughly right... unfortunately I remember very few details.

Comment: @starpilotsix Unfortunately, this is not it either.  But, thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_planet_killers

Comment: UFO? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CvURidpkCY

Comment: @Valorum Nope, not UFO, but it gave me quite a laugh.  After reading through the list of planet killers it seems more likely to be the first option (asteroids) than the second (planets).

Comment: Well, if we're going to name TV shows that aren't it, I'll have to drop _Red Dwarf_ here. Three characters, check. (Later expanded to four though). Deep space, check. Large ship, very important, which is their home base, sometimes abandoned and/or wrecked, check.

Comment: @MrLister While I don't think I need to say this, it is definitely not Red Dwarf.

Comment: There's this Swedish show, [*Vintergaten,*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Vintergatan?from=Main.Vintergatan) listed on the [TVTropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarthShatteringKaboom) for planet killers. I don't know if it ever aired in Canada. From the picture it looks YA and color-coded.

Comment: X-Bomber? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XD-9NZsYCQw

Comment: @JoeL. A very good idea.  Only, I doubt it was ever aired in Canada, and I know the show was English primarily and not dubbed over or something.  I now need to add no puppets to the initial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as I hate answering my own question, I ended up locating the answer myself while going through youtube videos of the comments.

The series I was looking for was Hypernauts.  From [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115210/)

> Three cadets from the Academy Of Galactic Exploration and a Pyrian princess are in a distant sector of the galaxy, when they encounter the warfaring Triad, who had destroyed Pyrus and other planets. Unable to match the Triad's firepower in their ship, they have to rely on stealth and speed to avoid their clutches. They must warn Earth, but dare not lead the Triad to their homeworld.

For completeness sake, I'll go through my list and point out where I was wrong and right.

> It would have been aired ~15-20 years ago in Canada (likely on the then equivalent of the Space Channel, but I don't guarantee that)

Hypernauts originally aired in 1996, making it exactly 20 years ago (Somehow this makes me surprised I still remember that many details)

> It was in English.
>   It was definitely not animated, no puppet people either

Definitely Live action.

> It was definitely a series, but I cannot remember the number of seasons it might have run for.  It could have been a rebroadcast of a show earlier, but it was definitely new to myself and the station at the time.

Sadly, it was a very limited run series.  Only 13 episodes made and 5 were never aired.

> There were likely three main characters (Could have been more, but three is a definite minimum)

Somewhat off on this one, three main characters and an alien princess whom I apparently didn't care enough to remember.

> Each character had a personal fighter/ship, colour coded to their uniform colours (I don't think they were designed as pure fighters, but they definitely had some kind of weapons).

This is probably my biggest mistake.  They definitely had the colour coded ships, but I apparently forgot the fact that they could also turn into mecha.  That probably would have made things easier to answer.

> The show took place in deep space and I don't specifically remember any kind of references to Earth.

Deep Space, check.  It takes place in a distant part of the galaxy.  Apparently, they just couldn't risk returning to Earth, though.

> There were definitely FTL jumps, but the terminology used for the technology escapes me.

Hyper Bubbles.  What an odd name.

> There was a large ship capable of devouring asteroids/planets for some reason, likely controlled by whatever passed for the bad guys. (Young me was likely quite impressed by it)

The Maker is a type of production ship that devours asteroids for raw materials.  Young me was quite terrible at being afraid apparently.

> One particular scene that I have quite vividly (probably from the series premier) had them exploring an abandoned wrecked ship, exterior lights flickering over the ships name (This ship was probably very important and likely became their home base, but I don't guarantee that).

Not actually the premier episode.  They discover the ship, ala "The Star Ranger" in the second episode.